# Precompiling assets issue while deploying app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am unable to deploy Ruby on Rails application to heroku, I am getting `Precompiling assets failed !`. Its working fine in my localhost. I can't figure out what causing this issue. Also added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in application.rb, but no helps. :(

Here is the log

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
       Installing i18n (0.6.9)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
       Using sass (3.2.10)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Installing rake (10.1.1)
       Installing ambry (0.3.1)
       Installing highline (1.6.19)
       Installing arel (4.0.2)
       Installing fssm (0.2.10)
       Installing net-ssh (2.7.0)
       Installing dalli (2.6.4)
       Using execjs (2.0.1)
       Installing orm_adapter (0.4.0)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing chunky_png (1.2.9)
       Installing differ (0.1.2)
       Installing httpauth (0.2.0)
       Installing multipart-post (1.2.0)
       Installing hashie (2.0.5)
       Installing redis (3.0.4)
       Installing oauth (0.4.7)
       Installing rack-google-analytics (0.12.0)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Installing newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.152)
       Installing ref (1.0.5)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing warden (1.2.3)
       Installing jwt (0.1.8)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Installing libv8 (3.16.14.3)
       Installing bourbon (3.1.8)
       Installing merit (1.6.1)
       Installing similar_text (0.0.4)
       Installing net-scp (1.1.2)
       Using uglifier (2.2.1)
       Installing net-sftp (2.1.2)
       Installing net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
       Installing sprockets (2.10.1)
       Installing omniauth (1.1.4)
       Installing faraday (0.8.8)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Installing leaderboard (3.3.0)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Installing compass (0.12.2)
       Installing activesupport (4.0.2)
       Installing omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
       Installing capistrano (2.15.5)
       Installing compass-flexbox (1.1.3)
       Installing oauth2 (0.8.1)
       Installing compass-rails (1.1.3)
       Installing activemodel (4.0.2)
       Installing actionpack (4.0.2)
       Installing omniauth-twitter (1.0.0)
       Installing omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
       Installing rvm-capistrano (1.5.0)
       Installing actionmailer (4.0.2)
       Installing activerecord (4.0.2)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Installing omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
       Installing mysql2 (0.3.14)
       Installing railties (4.0.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Installing sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Installing devise (3.1.0)
       Installing rails (4.0.2)
       Installing figaro (0.7.0)
       Installing therubyracer (0.12.0)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from newrelic_rpm:
       # New Relic Ruby Agent Release Notes #
       ## v3.6.7 ##
       * Resque-pool support
       Resque processes started via the resque-pool gem weren't recognized by the
       Ruby agent. The agent now starts correctly in those worker processes.
       * Environment-based configuration
       All settings in newrelic.yml can now be configured via environment variables.
       See https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration for full details.
       * Fix compatibility issues with excon and curb instrumentation
       This release of the agent fixes a warning seen under certain circumstances
       with the excon gem (most notably, when excon was used by fog), as well as
       a bug with the curb instrumentation that conflicted with the  feedzirra gem.
       * Allow license key to be set by Capistrano variables
       A license key can be passed via a Capistrano variable where previously it
       could only be in newrelic.yml. Thanks Chris Marshall for the contribution!
       * Make HTTP client instrumentation aware of "Host" request header
       If a "Host" header is set explicitly on an HTTP request, that hostname will
       be used for external metrics. Thanks Mislav Marohnić for the contribution!
       * Fix ActiveSupport::Concern warnings with MethodTracer
       Including NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer in a class using Concerns could cause
       deprecation warnings. Thanks Mike Połtyn for the contribution!
       * Fix Authlogic constant name
       Code checking for the Authlogic module was using in the wrong case. Thanks
       Dharam Gollapudi for the contribution!
       See https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/master/CHANGELOG for a full list of
       changes.
       Bundle completed (84.27s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/config/environments/production.rb:59:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_c4ee6d25-fbcb-4b04-85c5-5f602f951339/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Any help and suggestions are really appreciatable. Thanks

Comment: try to run $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile    locally and see if same errors comes...?

Comment: added ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production' in environment.rb and executed  bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

It looks like it says it's on line `59` of `production.rb` -- have you got any reference to a `split` method in your app (esp the initialization process)?

Comment: Thanks @Rich Peck, You saved my day. (y)

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

Please set Heroku Labs: user-env-compile by

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Comment: please don't use user-env-compile - it's being retired in 2 weeks.